# Converting Location object to Gson

Tags: android, gson, android-9.0-pie

I am using implementation `com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2` the version of Gson
trying to save Location object into shared preferences. I am setting  Latitude and Longitude of the location object to **Latitude = 23.456
Longitude = 77.65**. While trying to convert the Location object to JSON, The object is not getting converted to JSON properly when Android target SDK is 28 and this code is run on Android pie devices. The same code works fine on Oreo

```
public void saveObject(final String key, final Object data) {
        if (data != null) {
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String value = gson.toJson(data);

            // save in shared preferences
            mSharedPreferences.edit().putString(key, value).apply();
        }
    }
```

The image contains a [image: screenshot] while debugging. You can see the value of the variable value.

Comment: `The object is not getting converted to json properly`, which value for input location and which value you get after convert to json (in Android Pie)

Comment: I have edited the question with Lat, Long values. In the image you can see the json string

Comment: @RositaClerissaSerrao did you get any solution to this problem?

Comment: See: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1613. "You should not serialize/deserialize classes you don't control over."